# Compress image quality (from 4MB to 2MB) without losing its dimension

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I am trying to `compress the quality` of an image using `ImageMagick`. I mean that I have an image which dimension is `1600X800` and size is `4MB`. Now I am trying to compress the quality of this image into `2MB` without resizing its dimensions, means the newly generated image also have the same dimension as actual image `(i.e. 1600X800)` but the quality of this image should be compress into `2MB` (`half of the actual image`). For this, now I am using the below code, but this is not compress the size of the newly created image:

```
$src_img = "src.png";
$dest_img = "dest.png";
exec("convert $src_img -quality 90 $dest_img");
```

So can anyone please tell me what can I do to compress the size of the image without losing its actual dimension using `ImageMagick`?

Answer (score 5):

Try using ImageMagick and defining the maximum output size (in kB) that you want and letting it reduce the quality until that size is achieved:

```
convert input.jpg -define jpeg:extent=2000k output.jpg
```

For example, if I create a 2000x2000 image of noise, like this

```
convert -size 2000x2000 xc:gray +noise gaussian input.jpg
```

I get this 4MB file.

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 mark  staff    4175639 12 May 15:40 input.jpg
```

If I use the command above to reduce the file size

```
convert input.jpg -define jpeg:extent=2000k output.jpg
```

I get this 1.9MB file

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff    1933708 12 May 15:41 output.jpg
```

but its pixel dimensions remain unaltered at 2000x2000

```
identify output.jpg

output.jpg JPEG 2000x2000 2000x2000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.934MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Just for fun, you can see how setting different file sizes changes the quality setting:

```
convert input.jpg -define jpeg:extent=2000k output.jpg <--- 2MB file => 82 quality
identify -verbose output.jpg | grep -i quality
Quality: 82

convert input.jpg -define jpeg:extent=1000k output.jpg <--- 1MB file => 65 quality
identify -verbose output.jpg | grep -i quality
Quality: 65

convert input.jpg -define jpeg:extent=500k output.jpg <--- 500kB file => 38 quality
identify -verbose output.jpg | grep -i quality
Quality: 38
```

---

If you want a way to do something similar with Python, I wrote an answer that works pretty well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52281257/2836621). It does a binary search for a JPEG quality that satisfies a maximum size requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can change image quality using GD library functions. It is more secure than using `exec()`.

```php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("src.png");

imagepng($im, 'dest.png', $quality);
imagedestroy($im);
```